# Converting dictionary into pandas dataframe for printing?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary to a pandas dataframe before writing to a csv file.

This is the final part of a larger piece of code, which is designed to read in an input file, replace a perturbed variable, then print a new perturbed input. My input file is a weather data file with temperature and solar information as shown here in example_data.csv:

```
Minute  DHI DNI Dew Point   Surface Albedo  Wind Speed  Relative Humidity   Temperature Pressure
0   0   0   -27.9   0.66    4.3 67.30   -23.5   1007
30  0   0   -27.9   0.66    4.3 68.51   -23.7   1007
60  0   0   -27.9   0.66    4.2 68.69   -23.8   1007
90  0   0   -27.9   0.66    4.2 69.30   -23.9   1007
120 0   0   -28.0   0.66    4.1 69.69   -24.0   1007
150 0   0   -28.0   0.66    4.2 69.69   -24.0   1007
180 0   0   -28.0   0.66    4.3 69.81   -24.0   1007
210 0   0   -28.0   0.66    4.4 69.19   -23.9   1007
240 0   0   -27.9   0.66    4.6 68.38   -23.7   1007
270 0   0   -27.9   0.66    4.7 67.17   -23.5   1007
300 0   0   -27.7   0.66    4.8 66.84   -23.3   1007
330 0   0   -27.7   0.66    4.9 65.73   -23.1   1008
360 0   0   -27.7   0.66    4.9 65.43   -23.0   1008
390 0   0   -27.7   0.66    4.9 65.43   -23.0   1008
420 0   0   -27.7   0.66    4.8 65.13   -23.0   1008
450 5   59  -27.7   0.66    5.0 62.86   -22.6   1008
480 23  305 -27.3   0.66    5.1 63.01   -22.2   1009
510 38  595 -27.3   0.66    5.2 59.25   -21.5   1009
540 44  759 -26.7   0.66    5.2 59.65   -20.9   1009
```

I have a separate code which will take this input data, select one variable (temperature in this case), and perturb it. The perturbed data is returned in the form of a dictionary. I need to take the perturbed temperature out of this dictionary, put it back into the same format as the original input file, then write it to csv. The output file should be identical to the input except for the replacement of the perturbed variable.

So far this is what I have. I am using pandas to convert the input file to a dataframe, then into a dictionary. For the purposes of testing I am copying this dictionary to use as a stand-in for the one that will be returned by the external code. I then overwrite the perturbed variable.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "example_data.csv"

variable = "Temperature"

# Read in original .csv input file
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
  
# Convert to dictionary
varDict = df.to_dict()

# Testing purposes - copy dict to act as perturbed variable dict
pertDict = varDict
zeroes = [0]*len(df)
pertDict[variable] = zeroes

# Overwrite perturbed variable in new dataframe
varDict[variable] = pertDict[variable]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=varDict).to_csv("example_output.csv")
```

The problem occurs when I want to convert the dictionary to a dataframe and write it to a csv file. I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

From what I can find, from_dict should be the best way to do this, but I can't see why it isn't working?

Comment: Read the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html the default dict format is {column -> {index -> value}}. But you've set pertDict[variable] to zeros which is a list and not the  {index -> value} dict pandas is looking for. You'll need to create a dictionnary with the indexes as keys and zeros as values.

Comment: That was it! Thank you - should I delete the question now do you think?

Comment: Be aware that your input data (and thus your final output data) is not CSV, but either tab-separated or fixed-width column data (except for the header line). That is also possible with Pandas, just differently (with the proper parameters set).

Comment: And I don't understand why you are transforming the dataframe to dict to change a column and load it back. Pandas is a great library for data science. You could simply do df[variable] = 0 and you'd be done :).

Comment: Don't delete the question; it's supposed to stay around in case it's useful to other people.

Answer (score 0):

So IIUC you have a constraint that is the following, a function that returns a dictionary of perturbed values:

```
def perturb(var: dict) -> dict:
   """ Given a dictionary of values, returned same dict with perturbed values """
   return {k: v + 2 * (np.random.random() - .5) for k, v in var.items()}
```

In that case you can do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
temp_dict = df['Temperature'].to_dict()
df['Temperature'] = pd.Series(perturb(temp_dict))
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

That is, you almost exclusively manipulate dataframes, which is easier − except for interacting with the `perturb` function.

If your perturb function returns only a list of the values, such as `[0] * len(df)` in your example, you can do the same but need to specify the index:

```
def perturb(var: dict) -> list:
   """ Given a dictionary of values, returned list of perturbed values """
   return [v + 2 * (np.random.random() - .5) for v in var.values()]

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
temp_dict = df['Temperature'].to_dict()
df['Temperature'] = pd.Series(perturb(temp_dict), index=df.index)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```